# EF: Deleting object with bridge table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to keep track of attendances and students. For this I am using a bridge table. Students has an ICollection of PersonAttendances (bridgetable and bridgeclass), and Attendance also has an ICollection of personAttendances.

When a person attends a course on a certain date(property of attendance), in the attendance class the addStudent method gets called

```
public void AddPerson(Person person) {
    PersonAttendance personAttendance = new PersonAttendance {   
        Person = person, Attendance = this, 
        AttendanceId = this.AttendanceId, 
        PersonId = person.PersonId 
    };  
    PersonAttendances.Add(personAttendance);
}
```

So far, this seems to work, but I'm struggling to understand how to write a delete method, where the 'link' between a student and his attendance gets removed.

Someone in my group came up with this, but we are positive it wouldn't work, but this is the best we could come up with

```
public void DeletePersoon(Person person) {
    PersonAttendance personAttendance = new PersonAttendance {
        Person = person,
        Attendance = this,
        AttendanceId = this.AttendanceId,
        PersonId = person.PersonId
    };
    PersonAttendance.Remove(personAttendance);
}
```

Comment: Please provide your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to read the desired object from database and then try remove it.
 If you have an Entity for `PersonAttendance` (apparently your case):

```
var pa = db.PersonAttendance.Where(p => p.PersonId == 1 && p.AttendenceId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
db.PersonAttendance.Remove(pa);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Otherwise:

```
var att = db.Attendance.Where(a => a.Id == 5).FirstOrDefault();
person.Attendence.Remove(att)
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key of `PersonAttendance` is a composite key using `PersonId` and `AttendanceId`, you can avoid loading the entity first by attaching an object with the PK  properties set and then set the entity state to deleted:

```
var theCondemned = new PersonAttendance()
{
    PersonId = person.PersonId,
    AttendanceId = this.AttendanceId,
};

PersonAttendances.Attach( theCondemned )
    .State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Otherwise @rad is correct - you must first load the entity from DB (to get the PK) to then remove it.